# How to get id of selected Select component in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to get selected id of Select component in Ant design, the current time, Select of Ant Design return selected value is value of Options, I can set `value={item.id}` but when Select component is selected, it will display the id, not name of selected Option, so I must set `value={item.name}` and onChange handler will take `item.id`. How can I do it?

This is my sample [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selected-value-gfz6u)

Update: I realize that in my real project, I return Option with condition, if I remove condition, it's return selected id and show selected name, exacly what I want, what is wrong with my code?

```js
  const userOptions = user.map((item, index) => {
    if (!existedUser.some((current) => current.id === item.id)) {
      return (
        <Option key={index} value={item.id}>{item.name}</Option>
      );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are passing `options` to `<Select />`, you can pass the options as `{label: item.name, value: item.id}`, keep in mind that the change functions will now recieve `{label: ..., value: ...}` so if you want the id you'll have to get it by accessing `.value`.

Comment: I still don't know how to pass the options as ```{label: item.name, value: item.id}```

Comment: You can pass options directly to the select component like this: `<Select options={[{label: 'option 1', value: 1}, {label: 'option 2', value: 2}]}`

Comment: Using your data, you could do something like this:
`<Select options={user.map(e => ({label: e.name, value: e.id})) />`
According to ant, this has a greater performance.

Answer (score 3):

Change your value prop to item.id but keep item.name as the label

```
<Option key={item.id} value={item.id} >
        {item.name}
</Option>
```

Comment: In my application, I setted ```value={item.id}``` and label is ```{item.name}``` but when selected, Select will show selected id, not the label

Comment: no, I just need selected ID, what is wrong with my code? it's return id, but show id instead of name

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through your code in codesanbox and modified it as follows,

```
function onChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${array.filter(data => data.id === value)[0].name}`);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I feel it can help someone.

In your ant design select component where you would normally have

```
<Select.Option value={data} key={index}>
    {data}
</Select.Option>
```

change it to

```
<Select.Option label={data} value={index}>
     {data}
</Select.Option>
```

This is necessary as in ant design, we can only get the value by default.

With this change, your onChange function would now be:

```
 const handleChange = (value) => {
    setwhateverstate(value)
    console.log(`selected ${value}`)
}
```

What this means is that your value prop now references the id (index) of whatever data was selected.